# Cakephp validating specific field with specific rule without saving the data from controller

Tags: cakephp

I want to validate fields with Cakephp model validation, without saving the data, for which i am using the following code in controller.

```
$this->Model->set($this->data);
if ($this->Model->validates()) {
   ......
}
```

But here i want to validate only some specific field like 'email_field' and one of its rule 'email'. In model i have specified some other rules for 'email_field' like 'unique' and 'notempty' but i don't want to validate those rules.

How can it be achieved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have different options

you can dynamically unset those other rules:

```
unset($this->Model->validate['field']['someRuleName']);
```

or you can assign a completely new rule set to this field

or you can use a different "nonexistent" field for this validation, e.g. "some_other_field" with special rules.

Answer (score 9):

The above will work definitely but it's not an elegant solution when cake has already documented  how to validate specific fields of a Model.

```
   if ($this->Model->validates(array('fieldList' => array('field1', 'field2')))) {
       // valid
   } else {
      // invalid
   }
```

[For more detail see cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

Comment: Rules for 'email_field' like 'unique' and 'notempty', I don't want to validate those rules only i want to validate 'email' rule for which we need to unset, as given by mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
......
$this->Registry->validate = array(
    'email_field' => array(
       'between' => array(
            'rule' => array('between', 10, 100),
            'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'required' => true,
        ),
    )
);
$this->Model->set($this->data); 
if ($this->Model->validates(array('fieldList' => array('email_field')))) {
    ......
}
```